# Select files numbered like "file.00001" to "file.00431" for instance

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to select files named like : "file.xxxxx". Each x can go from 0 to 9. For instance, I used this piece of code for files file.0000x

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..9}
 do [...] file.0000${i} > tmp.0000${i}
 done
```

I would have known what to do if the files were named file.x with x from 0 to whatever. I thought about using 5 variables i,j,k,l,m corresponding to the five "x" ([0-9]) but it didn't work and I'm not sure it is the right way. Any tips ? Thanks !

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60257/how-to-create-a-sequence-with-leading-zeroes-using-brace-expansion

Comment: `file.{00001..00431}`

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't think it would work. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to work on existing files only, better approach is with <s>regex</s> globbing.

```
for f in file.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ...
```

and directly work with the filename `f`.

Brace expansion on the other hand will create all possible combinations.

Comment: This is not a interpreted as regex, but as "Pathname expansion" (i.e. globbing), which in this special case happens to have the same effect. You can't use a regex in bash to generate a list of filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf "%05d" "$num"` to print the number filled with 5 leading zeros.

Ex:

```
for i in {1..9}; do 
   file1=$(printf "file.%05d" "$i")
   file2=$(printf "tmp.%05d" "$i")
   : ... "$file1" > "$file2"
done
```